# Is there a way to prevent Walk-Me from loading, when running Protractor tests?

Tags: jasmine, protractor, intercept

I am trying to run a handfull of end-to-end (E2E) tests using **Protractor** and **Jasmine**.  I am using Chrome as my browser of taste; and when I run the tests in full-flesh mode (i.e. not headless), the tests all run successfully.  However, when I run the tests in headless mode, I keep getting an error that says the element I'm trying to click was **intercepted** by another element.  The tool that seems to be getting in the way is **WalkMe** https://www.walkme.com/.  I have used the following code to determine when my desired element is present, visible, enabled, and clickable, but this does not seem to help.

```
let isDisplayed;
let isEnabled;
let isPresent;
let EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

isDisplayed = await element(by.id(<locator-of-type-id>)).isDisplayed();
isEnabled = await element(by.id(<locator-of-type-id>)).isEnabled();
isPresent = await element(by.id(<locator-of-type-id>)).isPresent();
let elm = await element(by.id(<locator-of-type-id>));

await browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(elm), 5000);
```

Thank you in advance for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! You can't imagine how much I struggled with WalkMe... Here is the solution

```
// disable walkme for the session
await browser.executeScript(`
    if (!!window.WalkMeAPI) {
        window._walkMe.removeWalkMe();
        (function() {
            try {
                var envName = "none";
                document.cookie = "walkme_custom_user_settings_env=" + envName + ";path=/;";
                window.localStorage.setItem("walkme_custom_user_settings_env", envName);
            } catch(e) {
                alert(e);
            }
        })();
    }
`);
```

So basically you're disabling the integration, though by injecting a code to the browser's console

Though it's been a while since I used it last time, so hopefully not much is changed in their API

Comment: I will give this a try for the sake of it, since you took your time to help me out.  However, after installing protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter I was able to identify the real issue.  Yes, WalkMe was instead on the way; but the reason was that the browser was not honoring the code to "maximze" the browser/window.  The root-cuase of that is that there is a real bug with that code when running the Protractor using chome headless. So, after using code to set the window to a specific size, WalkMe is out of the way.  But, I'm still interested in your implementation.  So, Thank you!

Comment: yeah... see, this one will help you get rid of walkme forever, so even if it's not on your way now, better just not to rely on it, because it behaves unpredictably

Comment: After pasting `window._walkMe.removeWalkMe();` into my browser console and hitting Enter the WalkMe seems to be gone… forever  How do I get it back? 

Comment: I'd assume just reload page, worst case scenario clear cache. and even if that doesn't work I'd scroll through available methods of `window._walkMe` hoping if they have a method to remove it, they should have an option to add it back

Answer (score 0):

Another quick way to stop WalkMe from bugging you is to mock out your browser request to url `/walkme/i`, or whatever url your WalkMe script is sending API to(which you can check in your browser devtool network tab).

Quick example by myself in Cypress here https://liunate.medium.com/disable-walkme-to-avoid-flaky-cypress-end-to-end-tests-aaf73e213aed I think Protractor or other e2e testing framework should be able to intercept the same.