C# Selenium WebDriver: how to create a listener to catch an event?
I have a project with Selenium WebDriver and I need to catch an event when a certain web element shows up in the web page. It is like a button click from user in a windows forms app while the programm to be doing its stuff, but it program reacts to pressing the button.
And how to implement this logic in the test project?
// here some code

[Test]
public void WebDriverEventListeners()
{
    EventFiringWebDriver eventFiringWebDriver = new EventFiringWebDriver(webDriver);

    eventFiringWebDriver.FindElementCompleted += EventFiringWebDriver_FindElementCompleted;
    eventFiringWebDriver.FindElement(MainMenuLocators._signInButton);
}

private void EventFiringWebDriver_FindElementCompleted(object? sender, FindElementEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Found ya!");
}

// here some code


I've created only that: when the web element is found an event is triggered. And it works.
But how to catch an event without this code? How to create a listener which will listen to the web page and wait until the certain web element shows up? I need this to close some garbage forms like cookie files buttons or tips on the site. It is not known when such forms may appear.

Why would you want to recreate the wheel here?  You're using the right tool for the job.   If you want to do it the long way you need to create your own global listener.  You might wrap everything in a super class or something like that.

Why do you need an event? Why not just wait for the element to appear?

The problem is that the item I'm looking for may appear at an unknown time. It's like a sudden ad or a window about accepting cookies.

I suggest, by using Selenium IJavaScriptExecutor, to inject a piece of javascript that handles the event by clicking on the ok button. That way you don't need to handle the event in your selenium client.
Another approach what we are using is by using Selenium IJavaScriptExecutor to disable those non-deterministic tools. For example to disable WalkMe: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62565184/26824884

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, [edit] and try for [answer], describe the effect of what you propose and explain why it helps to solve the problem.
